# count subtotal as grand total from joining multiple table in php sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables like this

**Orders Table**

```
orders `order_id`,`order_date`
```

**Orders_items table**

```
orders_items `order_id`,`product_id`,`quantity`,`parent`
```

**Products table**

```
products `product_id`,`product_price`
```

**MY Expectation**

`I want to make grand total in last row and dynamically, I have built my own query and work to show data from multiple tables above, but cannot display grand total as I mentioned above.`

This my query

```
<?php

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE month(order_date)='".$_POST['bulan']."' AND YEAR(order_date)='".$_POST['tahun']."'");

?>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered display" id="report" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tanggal</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Harga</th>
            <th>Total Harga</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
        $query->execute(); 
        $row = $query->rowcount(); 

        if($row > 0){ 
            while($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
                $oID = $data['order_id'];
                $item = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM orders_items WHERE order_id = '$oID' AND parent=3");
                $item->execute();
                while($i = $item->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $pID = $i['product_id'];
                    $product = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$pID'");
                    $product->execute();
                    while($p = $product->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    //fech data
                    echo    "<tr>
                                <td>{$data['order_date']}</td>
                                <td>{$data['order_name']}</td>
                                <td>{$i['quantity']}</td>
                                <td>Rp. ".number_format($p['product_price'])."</td>
                                <td>Rp. ".number_format($p['product_price']*$i['quantity'])."</td>
                            </tr>";
                    }

                }
                    $total = 0;
                    $oID = $data['order_id'];
                    $rinci = $db->prepare("SELECT orders_items.order_id, SUM(orders_items.quantity * products.product_price ) AS grand_total 
                    FROM orders_items JOIN products ON products.product_id=orders_items.product_id WHERE order_id = '$oID' 
                    GROUP BY order_id");
                    $rinci->execute();
                    foreach($rinci as $r){
                    $total += $r['grand_total'];
        ?>
                    <tr class="bg-primary text-white">
                        <td class="text-center"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><strong>Rp. <?=number_format($total);?></strong></td>
                    </tr>
```

My query shows several rows as total based on order_id, if I change my query and group by another column the total is disappear. Here is my result based on query above

[Here's my table with several total rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPjQv.png)

**How to make sub total only show at the end of rows and summarize all total price * quantity?**

Sorry for my English.

Big thanks for someone who gives me an answer and solve my problem.

Comment: Seeing as you already have all the data in your rendered page, you can just use a bit of script to construct the totals.

Comment: Why are you going through the trouble of preparing your queries, and then dumping user data into them? Use parameters. Do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Probably this will work**

```
   while($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $oID = $data['order_id'];
        $item = $db->prepare("SELECT order_items.*, products.*, (order_items.quantity*products.product_price) as total FROM order_items LEFT JOIN products ON products.product_id = order_items.product_id WHERE order_id='$oID' AND parent=3");
        $item->execute();
        while($i = $item->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data['order_date'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['order_name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $i['quantity'];?></td>
                <td>Rp. <?php echo number_format($i['product_price']);?></td>
                <td>Rp. <?php echo number_format($i['product_price']*$i['quantity']);?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Strawberry your code doesn't work, thank you anyway

Comment: please mention a sample output then i can get your problem.

Comment: Do you need sub total for each order item or for whole order?

Comment: whole order item @NafishAhmed

Comment: @dhedheerik88 now i think this will work. I've edited where to place the query.

Comment: Thank you brother, I do appreciate what you've done, actually I've finished with this code, I did the similar way with you but my join table is not correct, so I've reordered mine into correct code.